# Umbraco - Search all fields of all documents which are children of a list of parents

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Our Umbraco 7 site has the following 4 top level nodes.

```
1 - Home 1 (Language 1)
2 - Home 2 (Language 2)
3 - Discuss (Bilingual, i.e. Language 1 and Language 2)
4 - Buy (Bilingual, i.e. Language 1 and Language 2)
```

Depending on whether the user is on a Language 1 or Language 2 page, I would like to search all of the fields of all of the documents of all children of 1, 3, 4 (if the current page is Language 1) or 2, 3, 4 (if the current page is Language 2).

Up until now I have been using a very basic search, where the user simply enters a value "query" into a text box:

```
IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> c = Umbraco.TypedSearch(query);
```

This would be ideal, apart from that it scans all of the documents (i.e. the root and children of 1, 2, 3, and 4), and does not exclude documents which are children of 1 or 2, depending on the language.

Is believe that I need to set up an Examine Search Provider and an Examine Index for Language 1 and Language 2, but I'm not sure how to set up multiple IndexParentId values, nor, how to scan all of the fields in all documents.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I realise that scanning all the fields may not always be a good idea, however we currently have many different fieldsnames for the sections containing "content" in our doc types, so right now this is the best approach for me.

(I originally posted this on the Umbraco forum a week ago, but haven't had a response, hence my post on here)

Answer (score 0):

You could make your query filter by path.

Say Language 1 root node ID is 100 and Language 2 root node ID is 200. Then if you're on Language 1, query pages where path does not contain 200 and vice versa.

Something like this: http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2011/12/limiting-an-examine-search-to-the-current-site